# Fail the script after all the errors in loop

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting

I have used conditional if-else where my script fails in case $? -ne 0 but I am running loop in it. What I want is my script o fail after all the check is completed. It is failing just after one check.
Below is my script

```
for i in `cat xyz.txt`
do
grep $i abc.txt
    if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo $i "is missing in the file abc.txt"
    exit -1
    fi
done
```

Comment: This script won't run. It misses a `do`. What check do you want to complete? The only check I see is the `if`, and that completes before the script exits. By the way, there is no need to check `$?` explicitly; just use `if ! grep $i abc.txt`. And you probably want the `grep -q` option, too.

Comment: As written, the `exit` makes it exit, ignoring the loop. If you want to make multiple checks, then set a variable to indicate a least one check failed, and after the loop is done, then check if a least one check failed and exit accordingly.

Comment: Yes..pls ignore do part it's a typo. There are multiple instances in the loop where erro code is 1 but script exits with very first error code.  I want my script to exit only when the loop is completed and show all the errors other than 0.[$ is missing]

Comment: @sharad, it's your responsibility to fix simple errors in your question. To suggest an answer, in the loop if there's a non-zero grep status, increment a variable. At the end of the loop, if the count is not zero then you can exit.

Comment: I get your logic , can anyone help me with the syntax please. how can I make my script to fail only after the last non-zero error code.

Comment: You can't exit "_only after the last non-zero error code_" because you don't know which one is last. You can fail after you've tried all the possible options (i.e. outside your loop).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set a reminder to fail after the loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

fail=false
while IFS= read -r pattern; do
    if ! grep -e "$pattern" abc.txt; then
        fail=true
    fi
done <xyz.txt

"$fail" && exit 1
```

This reads patterns from `xyz.txt` line by line and applies `grep` to `abc.txt` with each pattern in turn. If a pattern fails to match, the variable `fail` is set to the string `true` (after having been `false` from the start).

After the loop, `$fail` is used as a command and `exit 1` is run terminating the script with a non-zero exit status depending on whether `fail` is `true` or `false`.

The output of the `grep` command is written to standard output, which I assume you want, or it would not make sense to test all patterns after finding one that doesn't match.

Comment: This script works forme ..only issue is even when all the patterns match it still exits..I dont want it to exit when all patterns match as I have some downstream code after the script  as well. This script exits with error code 1 even when the patterns match. Script should succeed if all the pattern match. @kusalananda

Comment: @SharadDubey The script will only get to `exit 1` if `$fail` is `true`.  This will happen if any one of the patterns fail to match.  If all patterns matches something, `$fail` will be left as `false`.  If you have further code that should be executed if all patterns match, that should be added at the end of this script, after `"$fail" && exit 1`.

Comment: When I added a simple echo "Patterns matched" after exit 1..now it is perfectly fine. Before it was exiting.